# How do you change the class path to a jar file on intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

How do you change the classpath to a jar file or a different directory?

Comment: Not sure what's the purpose of this question and the answer. It's already covered in the documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Go to File-> Project Structure-> Libraries and click green "+" to add the directory folder that has the JARs to CLASSPATH. Everything in that folder will be added to CLASSPATH. Update: It's 2018. It's a better idea to use a dependency manager like Maven and externalize your dependencies. Don't add JAR files to your project in a /lib folder anymore.

I am attempting to add an external jar to my module's build path. I've added the jar as a module dependency and as a library, and the compiler is still unable to find the jar. I'm using intelliJ 14.1. I have verified that the jar is intact and not corrupt.

JAR manifest: IntelliJ IDEA will pass a long classpath via a temporary classpath.jar. The original classpath is defined in the manifest file as a class-path attribute in classpath.jar . You will be able to preview the full command line if it was shortened using this method, not just the classpath of the temporary classpath.jar .